# Derivation of form of perfect fluid stress-energy tensor

Tags: general-relativity

Given the perfect fluid equation:
$$T_{\mu\nu}=(\rho+p)U_\mu U_\nu+pg_{\mu\nu}$$
How does one derive the following form?
$$T_\mu^\nu=\mbox{diag}(-\rho,p,p,p)$$
I understand one needs to raise an index and use $g^{\mu\nu}U_\mu U_\nu=-1$ but I can't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a local inertial frame instantaneously comoving with the fluid.

Then in this frame $U^{\hat{\mu}} = (1,0,0,0)$ and $U_{\hat{\mu}} = (-1,0,0,0)$ so $T^{\hat{\mu}}{}{}_{\hat{\nu}} = -\rho \delta^{\hat{0}}_{\hat{\mu}}\delta_{\hat{0}}^{\hat{\nu}} + p(-\delta^{\hat{0}}_{\hat{\mu}}\delta_{\hat{0}}^{\hat{\nu}} + \delta^{\hat{\mu}}_{\hat{\nu}}) = \text{diag}(-\rho,p,p,p)$

This will not be true in an arbitrary coordinate system. For example just boost to a local inertial frame moving with some velocity $\vec{v}$ with respect to the rest frame of the fluid. This will introduce non-diagonal terms in $T^{\mu}{}{}_{\nu}$ since now $U^{\mu} = \gamma(1,\vec{v})$.